# Pipeline created by Job-DSL fails to run maven

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am trying to setup Jenkins. I am using the docker image BlueOcean. I am trying to create a Jenkins pipeline using a Job-DSL. When I create the pipeline myself, and run it, it works. But when I run the pipeline created by the Job-DSL, it fails because of maven.

I looked on internet, but I couldn't find a solution proper to my case.

He is the Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine'
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package'
            }
        }
}
```

and this is the job-DSL

```
job('PROJ-unit-tests') {
    scm {
        git('git://github.com/Jouda-Hidri/Transistics.git') {  node -> 
            node / gitConfigName('DSL User')
            node / gitConfigEmail('hxxxa@gmail.com')
        }
    }
    triggers {
        scm('*/15 * * * *')
    }
    steps {
        maven('-e clean test')
    }
}
```

Comment: We need a precise error message.